# Multibinding with generics

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to create a `Multibinder<A<? extends B>>`. I have tried using `Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), A.class)`. The second parameter is a `Class<T>` so doing this in my guice module gives me a Type mismatch error.

`Multibinder<A<? extends B>> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), A.class)`

Is it possible to bind these kind of generic collections? Maybe I could use a different kind of `Multibinder`? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a version that takes a `TypeLiteral`

```
final Multibinder<List<? extends Number>> multibinder =
            Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), new TypeLiteral<List<? extends Number>>() {})
```

Comment: In Guice 3.0 the constructor for `TypeLiteral` is `protected`, do you think I could use one of the factory methods?

Comment: Hmm looks like I have to subclass TypeLiteral, and create an instance of that.

Comment: Matt's example is how you're supposed to do it correctly: an empty anonymous subclass

Comment: I am getting a `The method newSetBinder(Binder, TypeLiteral<T>) in the type Multibinder is not applicable for the arguments (Binder, new TypeLiteral<List<? extends Number>>(){})` for the example above, any ideas?

Comment: For anyone struggling with the same issue as @orsg, check your imports. I had the same issue and was accidentally importing `TypeLiteral` from an Apache package instead of the Guice package.