# Using in Generics in Multibinder

Tags: generics, guice, kotlin

I'm a bit confused on generics when using `com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder` as below:

```
interface MessageParser<S, T> {
  fun accept(msg: S): Boolean
  fun parser(msg: S): T
}
class Parser1 : MessageParser<Mime, Parsed>
class Parser2 : MessageParser<Mime, Parsed>

class EmailModule : AbstractModule() {
  override fun configure() {
      val parsers = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MessageParser::class.java)
      parsers.addBinding().to(Parser1::class.java)
      parsers.addBinding().to(Parser2::class.java)
  }
}
```

This works, but loses all generics information. Is it possible to restrict this to a specific subset of parsers, ie do

```
val parsers: MessageParser<Mime, Parsed> =
  Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MessageParser<Mime, Parsed>::class.java)
```

Right now, this generates a compiler error:

> Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TypeLiteral` rather than a class literal to inject a class with a generic type (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-to-inject-class-with-generic-type). See [Multibinding with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519722/multibinding-with-generics) for a Java example. Below is the equivalent Kotlin example.

```
val parsers = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), object : TypeLiteral<MessageParser<Mime, Parsed>>() {})
```

Comment: I know this isn't part of the question, but would you know why this mapping won't be available in one of the same module's `@Provides` methods? Otherwise, works as advertised, accepting.